# UICollectionView scrolling not smooth when using NSFetchResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using *UICollectionView* with *NSFetchResultsController* to present the different sets of photos. This is the first time I am using both *UICollectionView* & *NSFetchResultsController*.

Here is my code :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyPhoto *myPhoto = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myPhoto.photoData];

    return cell;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
         return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
    */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:40];

    // Sort using the timeStamp property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor1]];

        // Use the folderName property to group into sections.
         _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]  initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:@"Root"];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When I have more sections and try to scroll the view, it is not scrolling smoothly.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why do you think it is the FRC causing the problem?  Have you used Time Profiler?

Comment: Yes, I have used the Time profiler, If I dig in to CallTree-> MainThread and so on, but not getting any help....did not find any method from my code which is using more memory....it is showing more Running time for -> dispatch_worker_thread2

Comment: Did you invert the call tree and check show Objective-C only?

Comment: Try this, open the simulator and do Debug->Color Blended Layers.  Are the cells red or green?  If they are red you have an alpha layer problem.

Comment: Cell are showing green, but header-> titles are showing in red

Comment: Is your "Allows External Storage" checked on the photoData property?

Comment: Yes, I am storing it as Binary data type with "Allows External storage". I have already posted the code for cellForItemAtIndexPath, in the top

Comment: Then you are going to need to dig into Time Profiler and Core Animation Instruments to learn more.  Those are the obvious things.

Comment: Try to reduce the batch size...

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between using NSFetchedResultController with TableView or CollectionView.

I see few things in your code -
1) `BatchSize:40` - the more size of batch the more time it takes to fetch. It will fetch not so often but it will take more time. try to set it to 20 for example. Scrolling should be smother.

2) You entity is photo.
- Make sure to don't store BLOB (big data) as values. It will make fetching slow. If you need store image in CoreData set (Store in external store file) key in you model.
- Make a thumbnail of image. If you need to show small size image, make a thumbnail and save it directly to CoreData (don't use "Store in external store file") key. This vill make fetching very fast, because you will not use any external files and size of Photo fill be small.
- prefetch data. If you have some sub-enties if photo and you are using them,

```
NSString *relationshipKeyPath = @"bObjects"; // Set this to the name of the relationship on photo
NSArray *keyPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:relationshipKeyPath];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:keyPaths];
```

Comment: thanks, I tried some of things you mentioned & now app looks much better.

Comment: you are welcome! try to experiment and comment and remove some pieces of code, this way you will see where is the problem